# How to find a database for proteins that bind to different molecules and have different binding sites?

Tags: proteins

I'm doing a study in which I'm trying to analyze the effect of molecules (ligands) on binding sites of proteins.

Therefore, I'm trying to find a database in which the proteins bind to multiple different molecules, and as a result have different binding sites. The database that I'm working with currently is from UniProt, and the problem with it is that it has proteins that bind to only a small class of molecules, and hence the binding site is similar for each protein-ligand pair.

For reference, here is the database that I'm using right now: https://bit.ly/ProteinLigandBindingSite

Can someone help me find a database which contains proteins that bind to different molecules, and hence have different binding sites?

Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.